# JQuery animate() to maximum height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with `overflow:hidden` and a set height. When I run `animate()`, I want the height to animate to the full size.

**For example, I have this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/aW9k9/

```
<a href="#" onclick="lol(); return false;">clicky</a>

<div style="height:50px; overflow:hidden;" class="main">
    <div style="height:100px; background:blue;">text</div>
    <div style="height:50px; background:yellow;">text</div>
    <div style="height:50px; background:green;">text</div>
</div>
```

**This example works, but only because I knew the total height of all the elements.**

```
<script>
    function lol() {
        $("div.main").animate({height:'200px'}, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

**^How can I recreate that without knowing the total animate height?**

Answer (score 2):

A Fixed version for @MattBall's answer, which use the `.outerHeight(true)` to include the inner div's margins.

```
function lol() {
    var $main = $("div.main"),
        totalHeight = 0;

    $main.children().each(function () {
        totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });

    $main.animate({height:totalHeight}, 1000);
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

If changing html code isn't a problem, you can simply change your html code like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="lol(); return false;">clicky</a>

<div style="height:50px; overflow:hidden;" class="main">
    <div>
        <div style="height:100px; background:blue;">text</div>
        <div style="height:50px; background:yellow;">text</div>
        <div style="height:50px; background:green;">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​and you can get height of inner elements like this:

```
$('div.main > div').outerHeight()
```

and also here is the lol function:

```
function lol() { 
    $("div.main").animate({height:$('div.main > div').outerHeight()}, 1000);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do programmatically the same thing that you did mentally to come up with the `200px` value: sum the height of the `div.main > div`s.

```
function lol() {
    var $main = $("div.main"),
        totalHeight = 0;

    $main.children().each(function () {
        totalHeight += $(this).height();
    });

    $main.animate({height: totalHeight}, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/CXyKK

Comment: Thats a good idea, but it wouldnt work if the inner div's have margins (which they do in my real version).

Comment: Use `outerHeight(true)` instead of `height()` to get the height including margins.

Comment: @supercoolville that's what [other jQuery functions](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) are for.